How do i fix error "net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: The system identifier of the principal output file is unknown"
I have recently upgraded the saxon version from 8.7 to 10.6.
The xsl:result-document worked perfectly while i was using saxon version 8.7.
Here is what i am facing:
This is my XML format :
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Statements>
<title>This is an example document</title>
<Statement>
    <Invoice>1234567</Invoice>
    <Name>ABC</Name>
</Statement>
<Statement>
    <Invoice>9876543</Invoice>
    <Name>XYZ</Name>
</Statement>
</Statements>

Here is a piece of my XSLT :
<xsl:template name="EnhanceAccount">
        <xsl:result-document href="/data/ebpp/{$FileName}_EnhancedAccountInfo.jr1" method="text">
            <xsl:text>InvoiceNumber</xsl:text>
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:for-each select="//Statement">
                <xsl:value-of select="InvoiceNumber"/>
                <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:result-document>
        </xsl:template>

And i get the following error :
net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: The system identifier of the principal output file is unknown
at net.sf.saxon.lib.StandardOutputResolver.resolve(StandardOutputResolver.java:89)
at net.sf.saxon.lib.OutputURIResolverWrapper.resolve(OutputURIResolverWrapper.java:58)
at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ResultDocument.makeReceiver(ResultDocument.java:528)
at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ResultDocument.processLeft(ResultDocument.java:477)
The file gets created and has contents :
Invoicenumber
1234567

After this, it fails. What is the problem here? Please help!
Java code :
            File stylesheet = new File(enhanceAccountTemplate);
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Templates cachedXSLT = transformerFactory.newTemplates(new StreamSource(stylesheet));
        Transformer transformer = cachedXSLT.newTransformer();
        transformer.setParameter("FileName", inpfile);
        Source src = new StreamSource(inputStream);
        Result res = new StreamResult(out);
        transformer.transform(src, res);


Are you writing Java code to run the XSLT  transformation? Show us that Java code.

did you try: <xsl:result-document href="file:/data/ebpp/{$FileName}_EnhancedAccountInfo.jr1" method="text">

updated with java code

<xsl:result-document href="file:/data/ebpp/{$FileName}_EnhancedAccountInfo.jr1" method="text"> did not work

The line Result res = new StreamResult(out); lacks the context as to what out is but make sure if you use an output stream that you also use https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/stream/StreamResult.html#setSystemId-java.lang.String- to set up a system id for the principal result.

<xsl:result-document href="file:/data/ebpp/{$FileName}_EnhancedAccountInfo.jr1" method="text"> works. There were multiple places in the XSLT i had to correct causing confusion. Thank you

If running from the command line, make sure that you use the -o option.
If running from the Java API, make sure that the Result or Destination object for the transformation result has a non-null SystemId property.
The href attribute of xsl:result-document is interpreted as being relative to the "base output URI" of the transformation, so it needs that property in order to decide where to write the output.
Alternatively, supply an absolute URI in the href attribute (typically using the file: URI scheme).

well i tried this <xsl:result-document href="file:/data/ebpp/{$FileName}_EnhancedAccountInfo.jr1" method="text"> . But it doesnt work.

@Pooja, same error as before? Or a different one (give use the full error message)? Anway, why the move to 10.6 if 10.9 is the latest maintenance release for Saxon 10 and if on the Java platform Saxon 12 is considered the stable/supported version anyway.

yes lemme try upgrading the version once.

<xsl:result-document href="file:/data/ebpp/{$FileName}_EnhancedAccountInfo.jr1" method="text"> works and with saxon 12 :) thank you
